# I am getting an error "unknown hyperlink target 0" when I try to run a Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I recently noticed that something was wrong with a Jasper Report I was running, so I downloaded the latest version of iReports, edited the .jrxml file with iReports, and compiled it to generate a new .jasper file.  Now, when I try to run the report, I get a weird error "unknown hyperlink target 0".  What's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this is the only reason this error would happen, but in my case, I compiled the report with iReport-3.7.3, but the software I am using to run the report uses jasperreports-3.6.2.jar.  Once I replaced the jar file with jasperreports-3.7.3.jar, the report ran happily.  It turned out to be a version incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using `iReport 3.7.5` with `*jasperserver 3.7.1*` without problem since Sep 2010. But now I'm faced with the "unknown hyperlink target 0" also.

I figured the difference of what I did so far was the other reports that worked fine were edited using iReport plugin, while this problematic one is simply uploaded via iReport plugin. So I tried opening the jasperserver report unit via iReport plugin, made a small edit, and replace the report unit with that file. Then it worked.