# unknown hyperlink target 0 in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I recently noticed that something was wrong with a Jasper Report I was running, so I downloaded the latest version of iReports, edited the .jrxml file with iReports, and compiled it to generate a new .jasper file. Now, when I try to run the report, I get the following error

> unknown hyperlink target 0

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You should post the jrxml file

Comment: It maybe because of version incompatibility. [This problem was already reported on Stackoverflow][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169308/i-am-getting-an-error-unknown-hyperlink-target-0-when-i-try-to-run-a-jasper-re